# How can I specify specific comparisons in the Lifetest Procedure in SAS?

Tags: comparison, sas, adjustment

I would like to make sure I have properly adjusted for multiple testing, which I am doing through permutation.  I do not want to over-adjust, so I only want to include comparisons that were specified *a priori*.  Here is a dataset that is similar in construction to the one I am analyzing:

```
data test;
  call streaminit(1234);
  do a=1 to 5;
    do b=1 to 2;
      do i = 1 to 8;
        censored = rand('BERNOULLI',0.5);
        if censored = 0 then ttd = rand('NORMAL',10);
        else ttd = 30; 
        id = 16*(A-1)+8*(B-1)+i;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

If I were interested in comparing each level of `a` and `b` to every other level, I would run the following:

```
proc lifetest data=test;
  time ttd * censored(1);
  strata a b / diff=all adjust=simulate(nsamp=1000000 seed=1234);
run;
```

Instead, I would like to compare each level of `a` to every other level of `a` within `b` (10 comparisons at 2 levels makes 20 comparisons).  On top of that, I would like to compare the two levels of `b` within each level of `a` (5 comparisons).  So in all that is 25 comparisons I have to adjust for, but adjusting for all pairwise comparisons as I have done in the above code accounts for 45 comparisons.  Is there a way in `proc lifetest` to just specify the 25 pairwise comparisons I am interested in?  If not, is there some way around this so I can adjust post hoc just for the 25 comparisons I am interested in?

While this is a very statistics-related question, the primary question is about problems specific to programming in SAS and not about which methods to use or the appropriateness of the chosen method, so I am posting it here and not on Cross Validated, though I admit that a post hoc adjustment outside of `proc lifetest` may be the way to go and so would be willing to let Cross Validated have a shot at it as well.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but agree it sounds like at least initially this belongs here.

Comment: Do you want a dataset as result, or do you want the printed output primarily?

Comment: @Joe That doesn't matter much as I can figure my way around that aspect of it.